# CSV to AVRO conversion in Azure

Tags: azure, avro, azure-data-lake

I am trying to convert csv files stored in azure data lake store into avro files with created scheme. Is there any kind of example source code which has same purpose?

Comment: Is the question still relevant? if so, can you provide more details: 
1. how csv shall be converted to avro: shall each field type be inferred somehow, or can you say all field types are number or string. Do you want it to be a field per csv column or an avro array for each row?
2. which language do you want to use? is C OK for that?

Comment: If you are looking to work with a pre-created schema and use it to convert ```csv``` files into ```Avro```, I think ```apache``` does offer libraries for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Azure Data Lake Analytics for this. There is a sample Avro extractor at https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats/Avro/AvroExtractor.cs. You can easily adapt the code into an outputter.

Another possibility is to fire up an HDInsight cluster on top of your data lake store and use Pig, Hive or Spark.

Comment: he asked for an avro outputter but you showed an avro reader. any recommnedations ?

Answer (score 3):

That's actually pretty straightforward to do with **Azure Data Factory** and **Blob Storage**. This should be also very cheap because you pay per second when executing in ADF so you only pay for conversion time. No infra required.

If your CSV looks like this

```
ID,Name,Surname
1,Adam,Marczak
2,Tom,Kowalski
3,John,Johnson
```

Upload it to **blob storage** into **input** container

[image]

Add **linked service** for **blob storage** in ADF

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

Select your storage

[image]

Add **dataset**

[image]

Of **blob** type

[image]

And set it to **CSV format**

[image]

With values as such

[image]

Add another **dataset**

[image]

Of **blob** type

[image]

And select **Avro type**

[image]

With value likes

[image]

Add **pipeline**

[image]

Drag-n-drop **Copy Data** activity

[image]

And in the **source** select your **CSV input dataset**

[image]

And in the **sink** select your **target Avro dataset**

[image]

And **publish** and **trigger** the pipeline

[image]
[image]

With **output**

[image]

And on the **blob**

[image]

And with inspection you can see **Avro file**

[image]

Full github code here https://github.com/MarczakIO/azure-datafactory-csv-to-avro

If you want to learn about data factory check out ADF introduction video https://youtu.be/EpDkxTHAhOs

And if you want to dynamically pass input and output paths to blob files check out video on parametrization of ADF video https://youtu.be/pISBgwrdxPM

Answer (score 2):

Python is always your best friend. Please use this sample code to convert csv to avro:

Install these dependencies:

> pip install fastavro
>   pip install pandas

Execute the following python script.

```
from fastavro import writer, parse_schema
import pandas as pd

# Read CSV
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

# Define AVRO schema
schema = {
    'doc': 'Documentation',
    'name': 'Subject',
    'namespace': 'test',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [{'name': c, 'type': 'string'} for c in df.columns]
}
parsed_schema = parse_schema(schema)

# Writing AVRO file
with open('sample.avro', 'wb') as out:
    writer(out, parsed_schema, df.to_dict('records'))
```

#### input: sample.csv

```
col1,col2,col3
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

#### output: sample.avro

```
Objavro.codecnullavro.schemaƒ{"type": "record", "name": "test.Subject", "fields": [{"name": "col1", "type": "string"}, {"name": "col2", "type": "string"}, {"name": "col3", "type": "string"}]}Y«Ÿ>[Ú   Ÿÿ  Æ?âQI$abcdefghiY«Ÿ>[Ú   Ÿÿ  Æ?âQI
```

Comment: Can you please add how can emkay run this on Azure as this was part of the question.